# Google Earth won't import a WMS service

Tags: gis, google-earth, wms

I'm trying to add a WMS service layer to Google Earth.
Service endpoint: https://services.bioportal.hr/wms
When trying to access layers, Google Earth returns an error:
"This WMS server has no layers which can be rendered by Google Earth"

But of course the service has layers beacause online viewer can show them:
https://wms-viewer-online.appspot.com/indexmap.html
because I add a known layer: dzzpnpis:zasticeno_podrucje_poligoni

I can also import the service into QGIS and see the layers.

So is there a way to add this layer to Google Earth?

Ultimately, I'm trying to extract polygon perimiter coordinates or trace the polygons so they can be imported into GPS apps.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89714/linking-geoserver-wms-layer-to-google-earth/